# How to switch sidebars in a spreadsheet where you are note Google Workplace member?

Tags: vue.js, google-apps-script

I'm developing a Google Spreadsheet Add-on with GAS.
I want to switch sidebars using `HtmlService` class method.

Below is my code.

```js
function showSidebarA() {
  const ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("html/A").evaluate().setTitle("sidebarA");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function showSidebarB() {
  const ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("html/B").evaluate().setTitle("sidebarB");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

There are buttons in the sidebar's HTML markup.
We can switch sidebars by pushing buttons.

However, it doesn't work well.

I failed to switch sidebars in the spreadsheet that I'm not the owner, but only the editor.

I don't know what to do, because there are no error messages.

---

Code for first displaying a sidebar

```js
function onOpen(e) {
  if (e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('sidebarA', 'showSidebarA')
      .addToUi();
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('sidebarB', 'showSidebarB')
      .addToUi();
  }
}

function onInstall(e){
  onOpen(e);
}
```

Code related to the buttons in the sidebars

sidebarA.html

```js
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-btn icon @click="showSidebarB">
        <v-icon large>mdi-arrow-left-bold-circle<v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    <v-app>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script>
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data() {
      return {}
    },
    methods: {
      showSidebarB: function() {
        google.script.run.showSidebarB();
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

sidebarB.html

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-btn icon @click="showSidebarA">
        <v-icon large>mdi-arrow-left-bold-circle<v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    <v-app>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script>
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data() {
      return {}
    },
    methods: {
      showSidebarA: function() {
        google.script.run.showSidebarA();
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: How are you executing the add-on? Testing it via `Test as add-on...`? What authorization mode are you following?

Comment: I have published the add-on! I execute it in production environment.

Comment: Hi! I filed a bug in Issue Tracker since I was having problem calling `google.script.run` in a sidebar if V8 was enabled, but the problem seems to have disappeared and I can successfully switch sidebars in an add-on using your code, even if V8 is enabled (take a look at my answer for more details). With this, your problem should have gone away. Can you check if that's the case?

Answer (score 1):

#### This might be a bug:

Server-side functions called via [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...)) in a sidebar are not executed successfully **if V8 is enabled**. Those executions don't show up in the execution tab

It doesn't seem to matter whether this is part of an add-on or not; a sidebar opened through a simple [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_slides_or_forms) shows the same behaviour.

If V8 is disabled, this problem disappears. Therefore, please consider [disabling V8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime): your problem should go away and you should be able to switch the sidebar successfully.

#### I filed a bug in Issue Tracker:

- [google.script.run not working when called from sidebars in V8](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172808991)

Anyone affected by this, please consider clicking the top-left star in order to keep track of this issue and to help prioritizing it.

### Update 2020-11-10:

This problem seems to have gone away by itself. I cannot reproduce this anymore, and I can successfully switch sidebars in an add-on using the code provided in the question, even when V8 is enabled.

Consequently, the bug has been marked as `Obsolete` in Issue Tracker.