# Can Google Slide modalDialog HTML javascript run server-side code? Environment Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-slides

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication
Do not list slides. Alerts in my code show the javascript running but not the server side code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
```

... removed CSS for simplicity

```
    </style>

  </head>
  <body> 
    <div id="parent">
      <div id="child">
        <?!= nextQuestion ?>
        <p></p>     
        <input type="button" value="Okay!" id="subBut" />
        <input type="button" value="Not quite" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
      </div>
    </div>   
    <script>

    // - - - - - - - -  LISTENERS - - - - - - - -
    document.getElementById("subBut").addEventListener("click", 
    function(event)      {
  alert("Begin submit addEventListener");
      goodJob();
      // event.preventDefault();    //stop form from submitting
    } );

      // - - - - - - - -  FUNCTIONS - - - - - - - -      
    function goodJob() {
  // alert("In goodJob ");
      google.script.host.close();
  // alert('Call flipDice' );
  
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler( succeed )
        .withFailureHandler( fail )
        .flipDice(); 
  
  // alert("end goodJob ");
    }

    function succeed () {
      alert('Success from serverside flipDice');
    }
  
    function fail (err) {
      alert('Handler fail - err: ' + err 
        + ' received from serverside flipDice');
    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The commented out alerts start and end goodJob and call flipDice prevented the dialog from even being displayed when they were commented out the dialog displayed.

I tried wrapping the call to the server in a try catch. This allows the dialog to display but the Okay! button could not close the dialog and therefore cause the call to the server. Of course the javascript involved 'not quite' could close the dialog.

Is something wrong with my call to server-side close. Neither the alert in the success nor the failure handlers displayed.

Console.log and alerts in flipDice did not display. This function takes a little time. I don't think it is a timing issue as the first line displays 'begin flipDice' did not display.

Can a slide call a server function?

The server side code runs fine when invoked from the menu. It includes console.log and alerts which are not displayed when it is called from the javascript in the html triggered by the button.

onOpen function with V8 turned off. The first line was commented out by the system when I turned V8 off in the run menu. Getting error "Missing ; before statement. (line 18, file "onOpen")"

```
//@NotOnlyCurrentDoc
function onOpen() {
  console.log('In onOpen' );

//  const diceObj = {
//    "1": "dice1", 
//    "2": "dice2", 
//    "3": "dice3", 
//    "4": "dice4", 
//    "5": "dice5", 
//    "6": "dice6",
//    "7": "dice7",   // lose_turn
//    "8": "dice8"    // blank cover 
//    };  
//  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(
//    'idDice', diceObj);
  
  let pres;
  let slideSet = [];
  try  {
    pres = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
    slideSet = pres.getSlides();
  }  catch (e)  {
    console.log('caught in onOpen e: ', e);
  }
 
  try  {
    SlidesApp.getUi()
      .createMenu( 'Ask ?')
      .addItem('Roll', 'flipDice')
      .addItem('BE1','BE1')
      .addItem('BE2','BE2')
      .addItem('BE3','BE3')
      .addItem('BE4','BE4')
      .addItem('Restack','rePositionDice')
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(SlidesApp.getUi().createMenu('Check Dice')
          .addItem('Check 1', 'checkDice1')
          .addItem('Check 2', 'checkDice2')
          .addItem('Check 3', 'checkDice3')
          .addItem('Check 4', 'checkDice4')
          .addItem('Check 5', 'checkDice5')
          .addItem('Check 6', 'checkDice6')
          .addItem('Check 7', 'checkDice7')
          .addItem('Check 8', 'checkDice8'))
      .addToUi(); 
  }  catch (e)  {
    console.log('caught in createMenu e: ', e);
  }
 
console.log('    after create menu');
  
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(      /*  spreadsheet with the questions */
    'dataSsId', '1fmZCittj4ksstmhh8_t0O0csj8IDdwi9ohDDL5ZE7VA');
  const dataSsId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('dataSsId');
//console.log('dataSsId: ', dataSsId);
  let ss;
  try  { 
    
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dataSsId);
    if (!ss) {
      console.log('Spreadsheet not found! '  + dataSsId );
      SlidesApp.getUi().alert('Spreadsheet not found!');
      return;
    }  else    {
      console.log('Spreadsheet found! '  + dataSsId );
    }
  }    catch(e)    {    
    console.log('    in catch spreadsheet openBYId: '  + dataSsId );
    SlidesApp.getUi().alert(e);
    return;
  }

  prepareQuestions(ss);
 
 // testing stuff
// const ckSsId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('dataSsId');
// console.log('dataSsId after prepareQuestions: ', ckSsId);
 // any one time gameboard setup here

}
```

Comment: I think the use of the `<button`   with `type="submit"` is rather unusual I'd make it `<input type="button"` since you don't actually have a `<form>`

Comment: Try putting the `google.script.host.close()` in the  `withSuccessHandler()`

Comment: @Cooper Using  <input type="button" value="Okay!"  /> did not seem to make any difference. Putting the dialog close in the success meant it was not executed.

Comment: For new readers I have another open issue with slides.  The most recent tests are getting try/catch error caught in createMenu e:  { [Exception: Cannot call SlidesApp.getUi() from this context.] name: 'Exception' } in the onOpen createMenu but the menu is displayed when the onOpen is run in the editor  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65615455/google-apps-script-custom-menu-createmenu-not-displaying-in-slide-auth-probl

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is your miscopy, I think that your this tag `<input type="button" value="Okay!"  /> ` has not ID of `subBut`. By this, when the button of `Okay!` is clicked, no action occurs. How about this? By the way, can I ask you about the relationship between your this question and the question in your previous comment?

Comment: I just changed from a button to input. There is a listener for the button. When I changed for Cooper I dropped the id. The javascript was running I saw the alerts. The server side code was not runnning. I will fix. @Tanaike please look at my other problem to as I quote you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I would like to wait that your question is updated by adding more information.

Comment: Added back the id="subBut" and turned on the alerts. The alerts fire so I know it is going to the send to server side code. The modelDialog does not display unless those alerts are commented out.

Comment: @Tanaike I am a retired mainframe programmer, currently teaching adults to speak English. Trying to take advantage of the script and docs to create tests and games. Slides: gameboard in the background, answer questions in modalDialog, If answered correctly the button -> bringToFront dice image - math.rand & then move piece on gameboard. Probs. 1. createMenu works in script editor not load/refresh, 2. roll the dice has to be triggered from the menu if the script cannot run on the server. I think that both Math & and pageElement moveToFront are only possible on the server side.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about your current issue and your goal. But I would like to try to understand about them. When I could correctly understand about them, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: Try removing `google.script.host.close()`: does the server-side function run? In my case, it runs but not successfully, **if V8 is enabled** (if it's disabled, it runs successfully). Seems like [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64752683) has reappeared.

Comment: @Iamblichus I ran with the google.script.host.close() in the succeed function. The server side code did not run and neither the succeed nor the fail ran. Turning off V8 in the legacy editor under the run menu changed the manifest and commented out  //@NotOnlyCurrentDoc in the onOpen but onOpen is getting an error Missing ; before statement. (line 18, file "onOpen"). I will add that function above. There is almost nothing above line 18: "let pres;" Because of error cannot run without V8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a missing quote in one of my alerts and now the server side script runs successfully. Thank you everyone. Sorry to be such aNewB

It still gets the auth error:

```
Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

When opened from drive or refreshed even though the item is in the manifest. It works despite this error.

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Mexico_City",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Slides",
      "serviceId": "slides",
      "version": "v1"
    }, {
      "userSymbol": "Drive",
      "serviceId": "drive",
      "version": "v2"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Final working HTML with call to server function flipDice

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style> 
  CSS removed for simplicity     
    </style>

  </head>
  <body> 
    <div id="parent">
      <div id="child">
        <?!= nextQuestion ?>
        <p></p>     
        <input type="button" value="Okay!" id="subBut" />
        <input type="button" value="Not quite" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
      </div>
    </div>   
    <script>

    // - - - - - - - -  LISTENERS - - - - - - - -
    document.getElementById("subBut").addEventListener("click", 
    function(event)      {
//  alert("Begin submit addEventListener");
      goodJob();
      // event.preventDefault();    //stop form from submitting
    } );

      // - - - - - - - -  FUNCTIONS - - - - - - - -      
    function goodJob() {
  // alert("In goodJob ");
      // google.script.host.close();
  // alert('Call flipDice' );
      try  {
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler( succeed )
        .withFailureHandler( fail )
        .flipDice(); 
      }   catch (e)    {
        alert(" google.script.run flipDice caught error: " + e);
      }
  
  // alert("end goodJob ");
    }

    function succeed () {
      
      google.script.host.close();
      alert('Success from serverside flipDice');
    }
  
    function fail (err) {
      alert('Handler fail - err: ' + err 
        + ' received from serverside flipDice');
    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify where was the missing quote?

Comment: @ lamblichus Sorry. I recreated the problem by removing the ending quote in this alert.   alert("Begin submit addEventListener);  The editor does not change the appearance of the code. I am not positive this was the exact alert but it was a final quote in an alert..

Comment: Does `flipDice` return successfully when V8 is enabled? I have to disable V8 for this.

Comment: @lamblichus Having V8 on or off did not seem to make any difference after I found the missing quote. The server side code ran from the html. It always ran when called from the slides custom menu.